# Remote screen control software (such as VNC) with permission mechanism

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

Does anyone know a kind of software that allows controlling of other computer, but the server can configure permission control? For example, the server can define five users, one of them can control, but the other four of them can only view. Also, file transfer support is required.

I've tried [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/), it works fine with anything else, but it just does not support user permission control.

[RAdmin](http://www.radmin.com/) can serve this job, but I wish to find some software which is free.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be to run two different programs.  You could run TightVNC and Teamviewer (both free), and just set up the two services differently.  Depending on which you're more familiar with...

- Set up TightVNC with control
- Set up Teamviewer for viewing only
- Distribute passwords accordingly

I use both applications regularly and have been pleased with both.  Both allow for file transfers.  Teamviewer has the added benefit of working across the internet without configuration, where TightVNC would require opening ports to work across networks.

Comment: Thank you. Actually the example in the question is an example; in fact, the case is more complicated than that one person controls and other people view.

Comment: Both softwares can be active at the same time.  Just saying.  Not sure if that impacts your more complicated needs.

Comment: Thank you. But I think only TeamViewer without any VNC software is enough for me. Very good suggestion anyway.

Answer (score 2):

[ScreenConnect](http://www.screenconnect.com/) can do all of that- you can define roles and give those role permissions based on the level of security you need to set for each role.  It isn't free but cheaper than teamviewer for commercial use.

> Use ScreenConnect Remote Support Software to quickly and securely access remote users' screens. With just a few clicks, anyone on any operating system is immediately connected.
>
> With ScreenConnect you can:
>
> - Remote control any computer over the internet
> - Access unattended computers
> - Share your own screen with other people
> - Support Windows, Mac, and Linux users
> - Support with Android and iOS phones and tablets
>
> [image]

Comment: oops i see you found a solution.  I find that wiki comparison useful as well.

Comment: This looks wonderful... However, it seems that this is not free?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [TeamViewer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teamviewer), which is free for private use. The linked Wikipedia article also contains references to further alternatives, e.g. a [comparision of remote desktop software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software).